# Regex get value in between tags with new line inside

Tags: c#, html, regex

could someone please help me with the Regex. I completely stuck

I have an HTML code:

```
<td width="50%"><span class="draw_info">Draw No: 2813<br />
Thursday&nbsp;10 Jan 13<br />
    <br />
```

I need to retrieve this line: `Thursday&nbsp;10 Jan 13`

I am using **C#** if this is of any help for you

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is normally a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583). Use a dedicated parser, like the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: XML is not a regular language. You cannot parse it using a regular expression. An expression you think will work will break when you get nested tags, then when you fix that it will break on XML comments, then CDATA sections, then processor directives, then namespaces, ... Try another way. Plus, what you posted looks like html. Use the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is more than just that *HTML* code in the portion you are trying to extract. Given the piece you posted, I'll try give you some *Regex* help.

I would start by normalizing the whitespace and removing whitespace tags like so:

```
var normalizedText = Regex.Replace(text, @"<br\s*/?>|\r|\n|&nbsp;", " ");
```

Then I would use a specialized *Regex* to find the proper `<span>` tag that you want (*draw info*):

```
var spanRegex = new Regex(@"<span class=""draw_info"">\s*Draw No:\s*(?<DrawNumber>[0-9]*)\s*(?<Timestamp>.*)\s*(</span>)?");
```

That will extract the *Draw Number* and *Date* values that you want into two separate capture groups. You can then access them individually:

```
var match = spanRegex.Match(normalizedText);

// TODO: Handle !match.Success for parsing errors here.

var drawNumberString = match.Groups["DrawNumber"].Value.Trim();
var timestampString = match.Groups["Timestamp"].Value.Trim();

int drawNumber;
DateTime timestamp;

if(!int.TryParse(drawNumberString, out drawNumber))
{
  // TODO: Handle draw number parsing errors here.
}

if(!DateTime.TryParse(timestampString, out timestamp))
{
  // TODO: Handle timestamp parsing errors here.
}
```

Comment: I see a few issues with this (aside from the general "Don't parse HTML with regex"): 1) Your first regex will remove everything, not just tags, since `.` will match anything and `*` makes it greedy. `<[^>]*?>` would be safer. 2) Even after fixing #1, the date part will actually not be the only piece remaining. It would actually be something like `Draw No: 2813 Thursday 10 Jan 13`, which of course `DateTime` wouldn't be able to parse.

Comment: Good points, I have updated the _Regex_ to better extract the data the OP was looking for.

While `.*` is indeed greedy, it will stop if it finds something that would terminate it, if possible. In the sample of `<.*>`, it will stop the wildcard if it were to encounter a `>` character.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, Definitely helpful for me!